# SAP announcement on discontinue PostgreSQL and other CF-services

Tags: cloud-foundry, s4hana

this week SAP announced the retirement of open-source backing services offerings like PostgreSQL, MongoDB, Redis and RabbitMQ starting with July 15th 2020. [SAP Blog](https://blogs.sap.com/2019/07/15/evolution-of-sap-cloud-platform-retirement-of-sap-managed-backing-services/)

They call it 'evolution'

Insteat SAP suggest to use S/4 DB (heavily oversized) or hyper-scaler external services, which causes lot of problems in enterprise environment (security, vendor management, ...)

I'm just wondering if

- there are any mandatory services a CF certified platform needs to offer?
- SAP should still be listed as a CF certified platform [2]

[2]: Beside that there is also a vendor lock-in to SAP CF by the SAP licence model (indirect usage) which contradicts the CF idea